# Reading log file of subprocess

Tags: python, io, asynchronous, logging, unity3d

I run subprocesses with lot of output (compilation of Unity 3D projects).

I use log parsers to find known issues.

```
class LogParser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.report = []

    def __call__(self, output: bytes):
        for decoded_line in output.decode().splitlines():
            self.parse(line)

    def parse(self, line: str):
        # Find known issues (using regexes for instance)
        # and append to self.report
        pass

    @property
    def std_out_file(self) -­> int:
        # default to stderr, subclass should overwrite
        return 2
```

I managed to use the [Python 3 Protocol API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html) where I inject my log parsers.  This is great.

```
class MyProtocol(asyncio.SubprocessProtocol):
    def __init__(self, log_parser: LogParser, future: asyncio.Future):
        self.done = future
        self._transport = None
        self._log_parser = log_parser

    def pipe_data_received(self, fd: int, data: bytes):
        if fd == self._log_parser.std_out_file:
            self._log_parser(data)

    def connection_made(self, transport: asyncio.transports.SubprocessTransport):
        self._transport = transport

    def process_exited(self):
        self._transport.close()
        self.done.set_result(self._log_parser.report)
```

Now I realize that on Windows **there is no way to get the log of a Unity 3D to be written in stderr or stdout, only in a file on the file system**.

In order to keep my API compatible, I add a condition for filenames in the protocol:

```
class MyProtocol(asyncio.SubprocessProtocol):
    def __init__(self, log_parser: LogParser, future: asyncio.Future):
        self.done = future
        self._transport = None
        self._log_parser = log_parser

        if self._log_parser.std_out_file not in (1,2):
            # If std_out_file is not 1 or 2, it should be a 
            # file path.  We could set a fileno provided by caller
            # code, but I prefer to manage async I/O from this
            # module
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.call_soon(asyncio.ensure_future(self.start_follow_file()))

    def pipe_data_received(self, fd, data):
        if fd == self._log_parser.std_out_file:
            self._log_parser(data)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def start_follow_file(self):
        from pathlib import Path
        followed_file = Path(self._log_parser.std_out_file)
        f = yield from aiofiles.open(str(followed_file.resolve()))
        try:
            while True:
                line = yield from f.readline()
                # aiofiles returns decoded lines
                if not line and not self.done.done(): # self.done is a Future
                    break
                self._log_parser.parse(line)
        finally:
            yield from f.close()
```

I feel like now I have two distinct pipelines for the same things.  I have read through the [StreamProtocol API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#streaming-protocols) and I can't figure a way to do it clean and simple.  Any idea ?